# Dynamically link static css in html

Tags: html, css, reactjs, webpack, webpack-4

I have a css file that I want to link in my html (served from my public directory).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/loadSomeFonts.css"></head> <--- this is served from public

  </head>
  <body style="margin: 0px">
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This css has references other assets as `url`:

```
url("/assets/fontsFolder/myfont.ttf")
```

When I'm developing my public path has a different url than in production - how can I differentiate between them using webpack?

Answer (score 0):

Add the full path of your files in html. if assets folder is in public folder then you have to add public as well

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="public/assets/loadSomeFonts.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `create-react-app` with the `PUBLIC_PATH` variable since it seems the easiest way to do this.

Could always copy the logic from there and use it in another project